# prevent chrome from switching to MSIE

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

I stumbled upon a website that calls `chrome://browser-switch` to send itself to MSIE. I would like to prevent this from happening, or at least having the choice. where can I find the setting for this?

To be more specific, the web page does a redirect (`http 302`) to `chrome://browser-switch/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.someurl.com%2F` and then the web page is opened in internet explorer and the tab closes. I really do not like not being able to control this. And internet Explorer is not my default browser. Chrome is.

I have looked through `chrome://flags` and  `chrome://settings` without luck

Comment: The webpage loads IE when you browse to it in Chrome? I think that's what you're saying...

Comment: Exactly. The web page does a redirect tothe web page does a redirect to chrome://browser-switch/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.someurl.com%2F and then the web page is opened in internet explorer and the tab closes. I really do not like not being able to control this. And ie is not my default browser chrome://browser-switch/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.someurl.com%2F and then the web page is opened in internet explorer and the tab closes. I really do not like not being able to control this. And ie is not my default browser

Comment: Interesting... Looks like a poorly documented Chrome feature, possibly related to the new [integrated Legacy Browser Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9270076?hl=en&ref_topic=9270153), though I haven't been able to find many details. In any case, it's not just something on your computer - if I go to `chrome://browser-switch/?url=http://example.com` on Linux, I get a page with the message: "The alternative browser could not be opened. 
example.com could not be open in an alternative browser. Please contact your system administrator." (makes sense, no IE here)

Comment: Looks like it might be controlled by Chrome policies. Suggestion: take a look at your `chrome://policy` and see if there's anything related to "BrowserSwitcher" or "AlternativeBrowser" (full list of relevant policies: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#BrowserSwitcher).

Comment: It seems that the hint to look at the `chrome://policy` was a hit: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#BrowserSwitcherEnabled ... I can't switch it off since I don't have registry access...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Behavior**

- You open a corporate site. For example,
  http://legacy_SharePoint_2010.com
- You will see a message: "Your
  system administrator has configured chrome to open an alternate
  browser to access"
- Your IE 11 will be opened and your chrome tab will be closed:

[image]

**Why this is happening**

- The behavior is controlled by the Chrome Policies (chrome://policy/)

[image]

- When Policy is setup, chrome://browser-switch protocol is used to redirect to IE
- The list of sites that will be forced to use IE 11 is listed in the  registry, under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\BrowserSwitcherUrlList

[image]

- You might need local admin permissions to modify or remove these registry keys 
  :